# json_encode() with large Unicode characters

Tags: php, json, unicode

When I try to encode Unicode character 0x10000 with json_encode() I get "\ud800\udc00". What do these numbers mean?

```
echo json_encode("\u{10000}");
```

Result:

```
"\ud800\udc00"
```

What does it mean?

Thanks.